# SQL does not order and group

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I'm writing this SQL query to kind of detect the users who logged into a system recently. The query I have as of now:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventName = 'Login' ORDER BY eventID DESC
) AS SUBQUERY 
GROUP BY personID;
```

Here's the original table i'm trying to read from:

```
+---------+----------+-----------+--------------+----------------------------+
| eventID | personID | eventName | eventContent | timeStamp                  |
+---------+----------+-----------+--------------+----------------------------+
|       1 |        2 | Login     | Login        | On: 26/12/2019 at 16:53:34 |
|       2 |        2 | Click     | Button       | On: 26/12/2019 at 16:53:42 |
|       3 |        1 | Login     | Login        | On: 26/12/2019 at 16:53:43 |
|       4 |        1 | Login     | Login        | On: 26/12/2019 at 16:59:22 |
|       5 |        0 | Login     | Login        | On: 26/12/2019 at 17:4:34  |
|       6 |        1 | Login     | Login        | On: 26/12/2019 at 17:5:6   |
+---------+----------+-----------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

The output i'm expecting:

```
ID  Login Time
1   On: 26/12/2019 at 17:5:6
0   On: 26/12/2019 at 17:4:34
2   On: 26/12/2019 at 16:53:34
```

The output SQL gives me:

```
ID  Login Time
0   On: 26/12/2019 at 17:4:34
1   On: 26/12/2019 at 16:53:43
2   On: 26/12/2019 at 16:53:34
```

Comment: Figure out which RDBMS you're using, and then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You should include some example data and what result you are expecting, select * is pretty dangerous, especially in forums where we have no knowledge of your schema

Comment: You stand a better chance of getting a usable answer if your sample data is representative of your actual data. As is the sample does not contain the columns eventName,eventID or personid and the dates published are not in mysql date format ,are they text?..

Comment: I have edited the question from ground up to explain the best. Look into the modified quesion @ChrisSchaller

Comment: I have edited the question from ground up to explain the best. Look into the modified quesion @P.Salmon

Comment: @ShrihariPrakash . . . Is the timestamp really stored in that very arcane format rather than as a proper date/time value?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just changed the time format and now everything works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want the latest `LoginTime` per `ID`.

With just two columns involved, you can use aggregation:

```
select personID ID, max(timestamp) LoginTime from mytable group by personID
```

If for some reason you need more columns from the table, then you can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.timestamp = (
    select max(t1.timestamp) from mytable t1 where t1.personID = t.personID
)
```

Comment: Thanks! your solution worked after I changed timestamp into a more proper format!

Answer (score 0):

Because your `ORDER` statement is on the inner sub query, it has ***ZERO*** effect on the final select.

Instead you should move the `ORDER BY` statement to outside of the grouping statement...

I have to question why you are using a sub-query at all, it is correct that using `select *` and `GROUP BY` will return a single record from the group, in other RDBMS this type of query is invalid, we must specify the specific fields to return including any aggregate expressions to use for columns that are not part of the grouping statement.

Comment: If more information is provided, including what the expected output is, I can update this solution to include a SQL statement, but I cannot easily guess the correct syntax that will help OP without a lot more information.

Comment: Give me a second I'll get to you with the things